# Create a Weighted Histogram in Excel

Tags: excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 and I have a dataset in the following format:

```
Pt_Count    Min_Z        Max_Z
45028       2.02174      2.08377
91236       1.98366      2.0932
2439        1.56177      1.61484
6844       -1.07632     -1.04243
4575       -1.09536     -1.04628
```

I want to make a weighted histogram where the number of occurrences a Min_Z or Max_Z appears is multiplied by the Pt_Count.

In other words the first two lines feature Max_Z values that are between 2 and 2.5, but I don't want the histogram to reflect a frequency of 2 I want it to reflect a frequency of 136264 (=45028+91236).

Is this even possible in Excel? Currently it works fine if I don't try to "weight" my values by using the Data Analysis tool.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a solution to creating a weighted histogram in MS Excel but rather an alternative method to achieve the same result. It's just easier to use python's numpy library to achieve this (not coded very efficiently but hopefully someone can improve it?):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Setting up empty lists
minZ = []
minZ_Weight = []

maxZ = []
maxZ_Weight = []

#Choosing bin values 
Bins = np.array([-1.3,-1.2,-1.1,-1.0,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = open("Height_data.csv")

    data.readline()
    #read a text file line by line
    for line in data:
        item = line.split(",")#Items in a csv file are split according to ','
        #convert text file strings to floats and add to relevant list
        minZ += [float(item[6])]
        minZ_Weight += [float(item[2])]

        maxZ += [float(item[8])]
        maxZ_Weight += [float(item[2])]
    #Creating numpy array (keeps the same order as the values were put in)
    minH_Array = np.array(minH)
    minH_W_Array = np.array(minH_W)

    maxH_Array = np.array(maxH)
    maxH_W_Array = np.array(maxH_W)

    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a=minH_Array, bins = Bins, weights = minH_W_Array)
    hist2,bin_edges2 = np.histogram(a=maxH_Array, bins=Bins, weights=maxH_W_Array)

    #Plotting Min and Max Z values separately
     fig = plt.figure(figsize = plt.figaspect(0.45))
     ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
     plt.title("Minimum Heights")
     ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1],hist,width=0.1)
     ax.set_xlim(min(bin_edges),max(bin_edges))
     ax.set_ylim([0,100000])

     ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
     plt.title("Maximum Heights")
     ax.bar(bin_edges2[:-1],hist2,width=0.1)
     ax.set_xlim(min(bin_edges2),max(bin_edges2))
     ax.set_ylim([0,100000])

    #Appends new values to the end of the numpy array
    combined_H = np.append(arr=minH_Array,values=maxH_Array)
    combined_W = np.append(arr=minH_W_Array, values=maxH_W_Array)

    histC, bin_edgesC = np.histogram(a=combined_H, bins = Bins, weights = combined_W)

    #OR you can plot them on the same axis
    #Plotting Min and Max on same axis
    plt.title("Combined Histogram of Heights")
    plt.bar(bin_edgesC[:-1],histC,width=0.1)
    plt.xlim(min(bin_edges),max(bin_edges))

    plt.show()
```

[image: Option 1: Histograms plotted side-by-side]

[image: Option 2: Combined histogram values into 1 graph]

For those interested Matlab is the only other method of creating a weighted histogram that I could find: [Matlab Weighted Histogram](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42493-generate-weighted-histogram) (but I have no experience using it at all hence opting for Python).

Comment: Nice work +1.  (Full disclosure, I can't validate it.)  I am curious, did you have this answer at all in mind when you made the original post?  I'm guessing not from your presentation.

Comment: Honestly not at all. My program is written in C++ using PCL (dealing with point clouds) and seeing as I don't have any experience in C++ at all I felt it would be easier to get Excel to do what I mentioned above. After stumbling across a python alternative I figured that solution would be just as easy/quick to achieve as Excel.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question "Is it even possible in excel?" Yes, its possible. You need to have Analysis Toolpak add-in in excel.

Programming languages makes it easier though. R can do it in about 3 lines of code or may be lesser.

Comment: I do have the Analysis Toolpak enabled in Excel, and it allows me to make an ordinary histogram but it doesn't allow me to make a weighted one, or at least I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: For that, you need to have an additional column for defining the ranges i.e. -1.5:2.0

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot I have the same problem, I have the additional column added. No help. Would you please point to the function name that takes weights into account? So far only FREQUENCY without the support for weights is available even with analysis toolpak activated.